# Editing router config files by hand

Tags: configuration, router, tomato

I use the tomato firmware for my router and I'm sick of the web interface.  Does anyone know what files correspond to different configurations?  The router I use is the Linksys WRT54GL.

Example:
the firewall is edited in `/etc/iptables`

Questions:

- Where is the wireless key kept?
- Where is the static DHCP kept? ("static dhcp" maps MAC addresses to IP addresses)

Comment: Is it just me, or does the lack of a tag or description in here of what kind of router this is make you not want to work on an answer?  >smile<  Sure, sure-- I could google "tomato firmware"... I've already hit the rep limit today. Somebody else, have at.

Comment: Maybe "tomato firmware" answers this but what router? From the message I'm guessing it is one based on Linux, but which one?

Comment: hrm... well how could I see the most recently edited files on the system?  I could make a change via the web interface and then look at the most recently edited files, or the files matching the timestamp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Tomato firmware](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) seems to be aimed mostly at use via the GUI, from a quick read over their [FAQ](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomatofaq). It is possible to do perform configuration tasks from the command line, but the documentation is somewhat sparse. It looks like command line access is there more for diagnostic purposes. Maybe it's time to give the more bare-bones [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org/) a go? (I recently moved from OpenWRT to Tomato for my home networks, just to stop myself from tinkering)

That said, the '`nvram show`' and '`nvram set var="blah"`' commands are going to get you a long way with command line configuration - nvram is certainly where most configuration is kept. `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` seems to hold the static DHCP entries on my system.